How should one deal with criticism from formal superiors (advisors, reviewers) when they have misunderstood the criticized aspect of the work?
EDIT: I already mentiond this in the last paragraph of the original question, but the most voted answer so far seems to ignore the point: This is explicitely not about the (frequent) case that the fault (directly or indirectly, e.g. by not having stated the point clear enough) lies with the one being criticized.I am fully aware of this and generally agree with the "the reviewer is always right even if they are wrong" mindset. But what to do in those cases where the failt actually lies with the critic ?. Not necessarily due to bad intentions or incompetence but due to them simpley not having allocated enough time for the review (which is common, given the heavy total load of work )
Common situation: Certain aspects of my work are criticized and changes are suggested: So far, so good and desirable—nothing helps more than constructive criticism.
However, in my experience, it is not uncommon that the reason for the criticism is the critic's lack of understanding or that they have not read all of the work thourougly enough.
This puts me in a dilemma. On the one hand, in my experience, expressing disagreement "from below to above" always causes a certain degree of tension and generally worsens interpersonal relationships (e.g., between supervisor and student). Reviewers may (even unconsciously) become even more biased against the paper than they already were. I know this from my own experience when I am in the "formally superior" position, e.g., when supervising bachelor’s theses. Despite all efforts to maintain well-intentioned objectivity "on equal footing," I notice how criticism from the "subordinate" makes them at least subconsciously less likeable to me.
On the other hand, I can't simply say: "Yes, of course you're right, I'll make the changes", especially when these are changes that I believe are counterproductive and, for example, would reduce the chances of the paper being accepted rather than improving them.
How should one handle this dilemma?
To preempt the most obvious objection: Yes, I am 100% aware that I, too, can be wrong, and that I may be the one not understanding the criticism. But that's not the point here. For the sake of this particular question, let's just assume that the misunderstanding does lie with the critics.

Maybe field-dependent. If you’re in the social sciences, you might be looking through different lenses.

This question feels way too broad. Yes, the general answer is "explain it better" but if you need more specific ones then this is covering too much ground. The way one can clarify things to an advisor who is physical in reach versus a reviewer who is only reachable asynchronously for limited time are totally different.

"They just did not put enough effort in understanding my great ideas" - why would they (or anyone)? And where does it leave you? If you failed to either 1) make your point extremely accessible OR 2) convince them that putting the extra effort into understanding will be highly beneficial. No one cares until you either make them to care or happen to align with their preexisting interests. Perhaps bit harsh and nihilistic, but generally accurate.

What kind of answer are you looking for? You can’t make people change how they read your work, so either you take their critique seriously and make changes or you don’t. Are you asking whether you should trust more in critiques and make the changes even if you think they make the paper worse?

This is precisely analogous to the case where a reviewer misunderstands your point in a submitted paper.
And the reaction needs to be the same: if your reviewer, superior, or anyone else in the intended audience misunderstood your point, you need to make the point clearer.
This may mean proactively addressing potential criticisms, especially if the misunderstanding arises because "they have not read all of the work thoroughly enough" - while the reader of course needs to read your text carefully, as the author you need to make their life easy, so that at least issues that can easily pop up are already explicitly addressed in your text.

Yes yes yes, make the reader’s job easy! Writing is hard and takes time, but a well written paper pays it back in spades when it is accepted without revision.

This answer actually illustrates my point ;-) I made it clear with an extra paragraph that this question is not about the (frequent) case of "the fault is on the side of the author".
you wrote: "that at least issues that can easily pop up are already explicitly addressed in your text." I did exactly that in the last paragraph of the question, yet it got ignored ;-).  So again: What is the best approach if the fault actually is on the side of the critic (e.g. when they simply did not allocate enough time for the review)

If you did already anticipate the criticism, and engaged with it in your paper, then apparently your engagement was not clear enough for this particular reader. This may mean that you need to be even clearer, or if you want, even more blatant, about your explanations. Or it may mean that your reader is unreasonably unwilling to read and engage with your manuscript. Without looking at the paper itself and thinking about what "reasonable" expectations would be, it's hard to say. At some point this crosses into "what to do about toxic superiors" territory, which we also have lots of threads on.

"then apparently your engagement was not clear enough for this particular reader. "
Lack of clarity of my exposition is of course one possibility, but not the only possible reason. It my also be the case, that, e.g., the reviewer actually lacks expertise in ths special case or simply did not allocate enough time for the reveiw.

" to be even clearer, or if you want, even more blatant, about your explanations. " Yes of course, but this can then put off other reades/reviewers (I for myself do not like blatantly dwelling on a point and see it as unscientific). This the dilemma I posed in the original question.

@zx-81 if the reader/interlocutor misunderstood, then you need to explain to remove their misunderstanding. I don't understand what other situation there may be here. Sure, it could be that they misunderstood because they're idiots, or lazy, and your text/argument was actually perfect. That doesn't change anything at all: they still misunderstood, so you need to explain. If you have a supervisor who is offended when their misunderstanding is pointed out, then that is a whole different problem that needs to be fixed since that is neither healthy nor expected.

Rule #1 of communication: what matters is the message received, not the message sent.  The onus is on the writer to be clear; if you cannot convince higher-ups of what you do, the problem is with you.  Adding secondary details is why appendices were invented.

@zx-81 "I did exactly that in the last paragraph of the question" Well maybe you should've done it in the third, second or even first paragraph? That's the exact definition of making it easier for the reader. If you want them to consider certain aspects when engaging with your work, tell them at the beginning, not at the end.

@walen - tell them what your are going to tell them, tell them, and tell them what you told them...

As a general rule, it's good to assume positive intent of anyone giving you feedback, and to look for value in any critique. So, often, even if a reviewer suggests a change you disagree with, if you think about it you may find there is a deeper issue the reviewer is bumping on, and another way to address that deeper problem. For example, a reviewer might say "in step 2 of your argument, you rely on X result, which does not apply in situation Y." That may be correct, but in your paper you are actually considering closely-related but unusual situation Z, in which X does apply, but you may not have explicitly pointed out the differences between Y and Z and that you are using Z in your paper. So in this case, you can respond with something like, "Thank you for your feedback; while I agree about situation Y, in fact I am in situation Z, and have clarified this point in the text."
For the purposes of this question, a more interesting scenario is one where the critic makes a point that is simply incorrect, and making any change to the paper would make it worse. This is an extreme situation, but can happen. For example, a critic could have misread what you wrote, and adding a clarification for their misreading would only add extra text and noise without helping the average reader of the paper. In this case, it is best to politely explain why you think your argument is correct as is. Sometimes, this might require doing extra work to convince the reviewer you are correct, even if you do not want to include this extra work in the actual paper. For example, a reviewer might say that Equation 3 does not follow from Equation 2. You could respond with a note showing step-by-step that Equation 3 does follow from Equation 2. This might be too technical to include in the original paper, especially if there are strict length requirements, but still could be part of the peer review process. There may also be the option to include results like this as part of a technical supplement to the paper, if you think it will be sufficiently interesting to other readers.

"it's good to assume positive intent" Yes of course ! but this question is not about bad intent but actual lack of understanding e.g. because the critic simply lacked the time to read all relevant parts of the paper. Thank you for the second part of your anser that actually addresses the question.

@zx-81 Yep I understood. I just felt it was important to start off with the "assume positive intent" paragraph, since I think sometimes, some people will jump to bad intent, and need a reminder to step back and think about if there really is value in a critique. So even if not your direct question, I thought that part might be useful for a future reader of this Q&A. The second part was basically more meant to address your question directly, and then yeah I think it depends on basically how important their opinion is. (...)

(...) For someone whose approval you need like a reviewer, I generally think if possible it's better to find some way to make them feel you have put effort into addressing their concern, even if you don't change the paper you can explain why and maybe supply extra details. Only when all else fails do you try to appeal to a higher authority like the editor and make the case the reviewer is unfair, IMO. For a supervisor, the situation can be even more delicate than peer review, and avoiding a combative relationship is a good idea, even if it means doing extra work to convince them of something.

You need to approach them as fellow-learners when they are wrong.  Some PhDs can get pretty sensitive to not being respected, so your language has to be couched in respect for their intelligence.  Write back with the idea that they are smart enough to understand it (even if they aren't) and then you'll be teaching them as a superior.  Sometimes that's just how power works.
You should probably try to get their position if they really don't get it.

I think your question is misconceived. The only circumstances (and circumstances that are completely unrealizable) in which your question makes sense in the form that you have put it, is that the paper is so perfect in all its aspects (typography, argument, presentation, referencing, etc) that no more could have been done by the author to improve it, and that had the reviewer only read it, then the mere effortless reading of it would have lead to the reviewer understanding and (probably) accepting it. That state of the world does not exist.
Moreover, the form into which you have tortured your question (and potential respondents) makes the question, as phrased, almost unanswerable.
It might have been easier and perhaps more fruitful to ask a very closely related question that omits the presumptive baggage of a perfect paper and imperfect reviewer. That question would be, "How might one respond to criticism that one feels is entirely undeserved", and the state of affairs that could lead to feeling that criticism is undeserved are more readily imaginable than those that you posit.
In answer to that question, which admittedly is my question and not the one you put, I would say, "Reconsider the (undeserved) criticism to see whether there is even the smallest glimmer of something that might be learnt from it. And if there is noting, learn to live with the criticism. In a full life, criticism that one feels is undeserved will be far from rare."

OP asks: "But what to do in those cases where the fault actually lies with the critic? Not necessarily due to bad intentions or incompetence but due to them simply not having allocated enough time for the review." [emphasis added]
I think the answer depends a little on OP's goals. Is the goal to convince this specific person, or is their misunderstanding an obstacle to something else that doesn't necessarily require their agreement (paper acceptance, passing a board review, etc.)? Both scenarios can be assisted by enlightening the reviewer, the later may also benefit from a procedural response.
As other answers have (correctly) emphasized, it's best to assume the good intentions of the reviewer, and that the reviewer is similarly situated as other audience members to the communication (e.g., if this reader doesn't have time, most of your readers won't have time). The response here is to improve your communication.
OP has already identified how the communication can be improved: They state several times in the question and in other comments that the reviewer is misunderstanding because they don't have time to thoroughly read the material. Unless OP can give them more time, they should accept this as a given. Their reviewer is competent in the subject matter and wants to provide a helpful review, but they are limited in the time they can give to the review. How can OP change their communication to help someone with limited time? There are many possibilities (e.g., restate something more plainly, include a summarizing figure, add a glossary, just make the thing shorter, etc.).
If OP is delivering some kind of communication to the reviewer, and they absolutely must get the buy-in from this reviewer, then this is the only option. All the reviewer will see is what they are given, so OP has to make it convincing to someone with little time.
Now, let's say that OP has done everything they can to edit and respond to the misunderstandings of the reviewer. If this is a situation where the reviewer doesn't have all the decision power, then OP can appeal to the person or body that does.
In the case of a peer-reviewed journal, this would be the editor. In this case, when responding to reviews you are speaking to the editor, not the reviewer.

Highlight changes made in response to the review:

"Reviewer's first critique lies in a misunderstanding of X, I have clarified paragraph N to better outline X and included Figure Y."



Or,

Explain that you carefully considered reviewer's suggestion, but declined to make a change:

"Reviewer requested a table outlining data series Q, however, this information is already shown in Figure Y and due to space limitations the exact numbers will be provided in the data supplement."



Finally, after all of the above—editing to make meaning more clear, explaining to the editor why changes were or weren't made—OP may raise their concerns with the editor. This message will be unique to their situation, so generalized advice is difficult. I'd advise sticking just to objective facts about how the review process had proceeded: "Reviewer A misstates several points (give specific examples) that reviewers B and C seemed to understand."
Outside of the peer-review process you may not have the anonymity of the reviewer, or the editor as an arbitrator, but the general advice is the same. If the reviewer is continually raising a point that you disagree with, just acknowledge that the criticism exists, what you've done to respond, and why you ultimately disagree.
